# Reversing order of integration for $\sin(x)/x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Any thoughts on the correct boundaries for reversing the order of integration of the following integral?

$$\int^{\pi}_0 \int^{\pi}_y \frac{\sin[x]}{x} dx dy $$

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should draw a picture of the region being integrated over.

Comment: See this link for a quick guide on how to write math in your posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

The region of integration is given by $0\leq y\leq\pi$ and $y\leq x \leq \pi$, hence by reversing the order of integration we have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x\,dx = \color{red}{2}.$$